# How to wait for a resource to be ready in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-efs

I'm building a terraform config file that is supposed to do the following

- Create an EFS file system
- Create an EFS access point
- Create an EFS mount target
- Create a few lambda functions that will use this mount target

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "pki_efs" {
    tags = var.global_tags
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "pki_efs_mount_target" {
    file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.pki_efs.id
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.private_subnet.id
    security_groups = [ aws_security_group.lambda_security_group.id ]
}

resource "aws_efs_access_point" "xxx_efs_access_point" {
    file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.pki_efs.id
    root_directory {
      creation_info {
        owner_gid = 0
        owner_uid = 0
        permissions = 777
      }
      path = "/xxx"
    }
    tags = var.global_tags
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "generate_xxx_lambda_function" {
    tags = var.global_tags
    function_name = format("xxx-%s", var.global_tags.app)
    file_system_config {
        arn = aws_efs_access_point.pki_efs_access_point.arn
        local_mount_path = "/mnt/xxx"
    }

    publish = true
    vpc_config {
        security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.lambda_security_group.id ]
        subnet_ids = [ aws_subnet.private_subnet.id ]
    }
    image_uri = var.connection_pack_function_image
    package_type = "Image"
    role = var.lambda_role_arn
    timeout = 60
}
```

The thing is, you cannot create lambda functions using a mount target that is not on a "ready" state. Which is why I get the following error from the API :

```
aws_efs_mount_target.pki_efs_mount_target: Creation complete after 1m24s [id=fsmt-<REDACTED>]

Error: error creating Lambda Function (1): InvalidParameterValueException: EFS file system arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-west-2:<REDACTED>:file-system/fs-<REDACTED> referenced by access point arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-west-2:<REDACTED>:access-point/fsap-<REDACTED> has mount targets created in all availability zones the function will execute in, but not all are in the available life cycle state yet. Please wait for them to become available and try the request again.
```

How could i tell Terraform to wait for the mount target to be on the READY state before creating the lambda functions ?

I know that I could create a `time_sleep` resource but it doesn't seem very elegant... Because that way, you don't really make sure the resource is indeed ready, you just wait an arbitrary amount of time that could be enough or too much depending on what happens.

Comment: What is the code you are using? Can you add that to the question as well?

Comment: ok I added a code sample

Comment: Great. Does your SG allow the EFS port, in other words is Lambda allowed to communicate with EFS?

Comment: yes. the setup itself works. i created everything manually first for the test. check the error message i mentionned